# NOT NULL constraint Failed in Flask + SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I got this error in my app flask

```
IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed:
         auth_user.role [SQL: u'INSERT INTO auth_user (username, email, password, role, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)']
     [parameters: (u'Natali', u'mail@gmail.com', 'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$p8jlOhqU$fa51e0491a729cef6d05dbd9f1d868455de4be9c', None, None)]
```

However, I think that the code is fine.
I don't know why doesn't work properly, the values that are as None are allowed to do it, because null=True.

My files are the following

This is my models.py

```
from app import db
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

    class User(db.Model):

        __tablename__ = 'auth_user'

        id      = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False)
        email    = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False,
                          unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(192),  nullable=False)
        role     = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=True)
        status   = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=True)

        def __init__(self, username, email, password):

            self.username = username.title()
            self.email    = email.lower()
            self.password = generate_password_hash(password)

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<User %r>' % (self.name)

        def set_password(self, password):
            self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

        def check_password(self, password):
            return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)
```

And this is my controller.py

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint,
    request,
    render_template,
    flash,
    g,
    session,
    redirect,
    url_for
)
from werkzeug import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from app import db
from app.authentication.forms import LoginForm, SignupForm
from app.authentication.models import User

mod_auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

@mod_auth.route('/profile')
def profile():

    if 'email' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))

    user = User.query.filter_by(email = session['email']).first()

    if user is None:
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    else:
        return render_template('authentication/profile.html')

@mod_auth.route('/signup/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():

    form = SignupForm()

    if 'email' is session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return render_template("authentication/signup.html", form=form)
        else:
            new_user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()

            session['email'] = new_user.email
            return "Not found"

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("authentication/signup.html", form=form)


@mod_auth.route('/signin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():

    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            flash('Welcome %s' % user.name)
            return redirect(url_for('auth.home'))

        flash('Wrong email or password', 'error-message')

    return render_template("authentication/signin.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem when I define my Model `id` as BIGINT, but my test code use `sqlite` as test database, when I change my Model defination, problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

You can examine the database schema by starting the SQLite shell and using the `.schema` command.

```
$ sqlite3 app.db
sqlite> .schema user
```

At some point, your model had `nullable=False` set on the `role` column.  You created the database with this model, then changed it to `True`.  Changing the model after the database was created does not change the database, you need to migrate it.  Use [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/) to migrate a SQLAlchemy database.

Answer (score -2):

in flask project, if U use the sqlite database, If the id in the model is set to BIGINT, an error will be occured when do `db.session.commit()`：`UNIQUE constraint failed: tablename.column_name`.

then you can resolve it by：

delete the table in the database, add the attribute `AUTOINCREMENT`, then recreate this table and be resolved:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
   id   BIGINT  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,`
   ...
```